# Visual code debug error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, sails.js, visual-studio-code, enoent

iam new in node.js sails framework.  i have installed sails and created my first application using command

```
sails new testapp
```

i have successfully running/debugging my sample application using visual studio code. 
But i cant debug my another code created using sails.when trying to debug the application, visual studio debugger produce error like this

```
node --debug-brk=42607 --nolazy app.js 
Debugger listening on port 42607
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }
```

What is the actual issue related with this?

Comment: Something is trying to open ".env". Can you run this application without debugging in vscode? If not, there's something wrong with your app. If so, then post your launch config.

Comment: i have successfully run this application on terminal using sails lift command.

Comment: But i cant debug this application using command sails debug.

Comment: Facing the same here.. 
Did u find any solution ?